# Android Native alternative to AirPlay

Tags: streaming, airplay

I want to give my old apple TV to my parents because my dad wants to stream files from his ipad to his tv. 2 Months ago I made the Switch from iOS to Android, 1.5 Years ago the switch from MAc to Linux.

So I am now looking for a great alternative to Stream all that Media contents, but at least the Audio/Music from my Android Phone around my small flat (TV, Sound System in Living Room and some small Speakers in my bathroom)

Is there a native way to do that, such as airplay in the apple world? Would be great, when the receivers would not be as expensive as an apple TV so less then ~100€ and would also work with pulseaudio (ubuntu)

Ah, forgot to mention: It should be weather built in to the core android system or be a future of poweramp to save battery life and not messing around with another daemon.

Answer (score 0):

Google uses Miracast for its media streaming and most recent devices can use it. As for the receiver, recent TVs have Miracast built in. If your TV doesn't have it, there are some adapters on Amazon.

Comment: my TV is quite old, well, It has ... hmm TV built in, yep ;-)
Does it work on android like it worked on Apple, that I can somewhere in a central menu chose where the sound should go to?

Comment: For screen mirroring, there's an option in the Settings app but I think you need an app for audio only

Comment: Byung-Hoon You need to tag @Tobi using the @ symbol so that he gets notified of your update / comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Chrome Cast](http://www.google.com/chrome/devices/chromecast/). It can even stream online music by itself making your Android only a remote control sleeping during the streaming and saving battery life. 
If you sync your music library to [Google Music](https://music.google.com) (even in free account) you will be able to control it by native [Google Music app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.music).

HDMI output can be converted to jack or cinch by adapter if your HiFi does not support them.

Google also introduced [Cast for Audio](http://www.google.com/cast/audio/) specialized only to Audio, and some HiFi companies started to integrate it into their speakers or receivers.

Another option is streaming to any bluetooth reciever. Either integrated in HiFi or [standalone Bluetooth audio adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IQBSW28).